# Deleting my data in my table but not in database

Tags: mysql, database

I have a query here. I wanted to delete my data in my browser table but I dont want it to be deleted permanently, I just want it to be hidden. My problem is I don't know what kind of query will I be needing. Here is my delete query.

My table feilds are Id Name and Flag. I want to do is when the flag is 1 it shows up the table and if it is 0 it will be hidden when the delete button is pressed.

```
function delete()
    {
        $id = $this->input->get('id');
        $sSQL = "DELETE FROM tableq where id = ?";
        $this->db->query($sSQL, array($id)); 
    }
```

Comment: if you don't want to delete from database then **Don't** ever do this `DELETE FROM tableq where id = ?`!

Answer (score 3):

You can just update the flag, and in your select query select only `flag=1` Try this,

```
  $sSQL = "update tableq set `flag` =0 where id = ?";
  $this->db->query($sSQL, array($id));
```